# Is there a 'kosher' way to display options in a select tag as a list of links, and NOT a drop-down?

Tags: forms, codeigniter

My problem is that I am making a dynamic generated form using codeigniter. I need my dynamic results to be made into links. These 'links' are contained within a form and when clicked, should pass an item_id. The displayed link however should portray the item_name. I have both the id and name of every product within a foreach, gathered from a query. The reason I am doing it like this and not having them as a radio/drop-down, is because I'm attempting to make this touchscreen friendly. I need to have them list out as links. I am trying to stay away from javascript on this if I can. Just wondering if anyone had an idea of what I could do here. As I asked in my title, what I am looking for is a way to make form inputs as if they where select/option but listed as links. I also tried them as submit tags, but then I cannot display the name and have the value as the id.

EDIT:
I should also add that $key is the id of each product and $info is the name.

```
foreach($products as $key => $info):
?>
    <div class="field_row clearfix">
<?php
   /* NEED THE FORM ELEMENTS HERE */
?>
</div>
<?php
endforeach;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could have links with an onClick attribute that sets hidden input element?

Comment: Sorry, missed the point of avoiding javascript..

Answer (score 1):

You could use [jquery](http://jquery.com/) and [js metadata](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Metadata) to achieve this.

*N.B. untested code of the top of my head.*

```
<?php
foreach ($products as $key => $info)
{
?>
    <div class="product-link {item_id: <?php echo $key; ?>}">
        <?php echo $info; ?>
    </div>
<?php
}
?>

<script type=text/javascript">
/*<![CDATA[*/
$(document).ready(function() {
    // listen event on drop down
    $(".product-link").click(function () {
        var item_id = $(this).metadata().item_id;
        // do what ever you want here, maybe a redirect
        window.location.href = "/products/items/"+item_id;
    });
});
/*]]>*/
</script>
```

Comment: I guess I have no choice, but to do javascript. I like this answer, but I'm going to do something a little more simple. Thank you all for you time.